# Trigger a new pipeline on merge request creation in gitlab-ci

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, merge-request

i have a mono repo structure and created a pipeline that only runs for specific sub folders which have changed.
Now if i change something in Context1 and the pipeline does not succeed, and then change something in Context2 and the pipeline succeeds, a created merge request would say it is mergeable because the last pipeline succeeded.

How can i trigger a new pipeline on a merge request that runs the pipeline that runs for all sub folders? (Not asking how to create such a pipeline, only how to trigger one)

Comment: Do you have an excerpt from your pipeline to provide more context?

Comment: No i can not share sadly, but i can describe the basic idea.
Basically the pipeline has 1 initial job that creates a pipeline.yaml which contains jobs for every folder there is, and has the only changes gitlab-ci trigger, so every folder has a dynamically created job which only runs on changes for that specific folder